# How to show error message in login page when user fail to login with Spring Boot?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Now i am doing project with Spring Boot. I wanted to show error message when I fail to login. When I did Maven project I did it easily with BindingResult. I followed several instruction to complete the task what I wanted to do. But I couldn't get any proper solution. I need a proper solution in simplest way.

Here my `Controller` class

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkLogin(@RequestParam String roll, @RequestParam String pass) {
        if (studentService.existsByRollAndPass(roll, pass)) {
            return "Welcome";
        } else {
            return "Login";
        }
```

And my `html` file is

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/loginCheck">

        <fieldset>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Roll</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="textInput" name="roll" type="text"
                           placeholder="Roll" class="form-control input-md">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="password" name="pass" type="password"
                           placeholder="password" class="form-control input-md">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="login"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can put an error parameter to the URL like localhost:8080/login?error. Then, with the help of Thymeleaf, you can add this div to the html.

```
<div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">    
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
```

This div will be displayed if there is an error parameter at the URL.

However, you may need to change

```
return "Login"
```

to

```
return "redirect:Login?error";
```

Comment: I tried ! But  ${param.error}  this one giving error. "Cannot resolve 'param' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates unresolved references and invalid expressions".

Comment: It works @Avijit Barua please check in your Thymleaf header you have the `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` and also make sure that  Thymleaf is on your classpath!

Comment: this always says Invalid username and password even if user be inactive.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting 3 hours i solved this problem. I changed my `html` header

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
```

to

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sf="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
```

And added `Model` in `Controller` class. Now my controller class is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkLogin(@RequestParam String roll, @RequestParam String pass, Model model) {
           if (studentService.existsByRollAndPass(roll, pass))
           {
            return "Welcome";
           }
            else
           {
               model.addAttribute("logError","logError");
               return "Login";
           }
        }
```

To catch the error I put a single line code in `html` file.

```
<span th:if="${logError != null}" class="error">Wrong user or password</span>
```

Everything working fine now !!!

Comment: Yes but did you try <html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">. Do you use JSP or Thymeleaf?. th tag is used for Thymeleaf.

Comment: And yeah, putting an attribute at model is better choice than mine.

Comment: Thank you @funky-nd :) !

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by implementing an AuthenticationFailureHandler and redirecting with a parameter to indicate that there was a login error.

In your class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, in the override of the configure method, make sure to add your failureHandler

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    .failureHandler(getAuthenticationFailureHandler())
    ...
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler getAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
```

And in your class that implements AuthenticationFailureHandler (ex: MyAuthenticationFailureHandler), implement the onAuthenticationFailure method and redirect to the login page and add a parameter to the URL such as loginError=true.

```
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/login?loginError=true");
    }
```

Then in your login.html page, use ${param.loginError} to check for this URL parameter.

```
<p class="text-danger" th:if="${param.loginError}" th:text="'Wrong username or password'"></p>
```